# scroll(0,0) working while scrollTo(0,0) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrolltop

Ehy guys. I have a strange kind of problem. I've created a button to scroll the page to the bottom when the user clicks it, and it works only if I use scroll(0,0), while if I use scrollTo(0,0) (which should work in the same way I guess) doesn't work (the page doesn't scroll, nothing happens). Here is a part of code: this is the function which should scroll to the top after click using scrollTo but which doesn't do anything.

```
<button id="scrollaInAlto" onClick="scrollInAlto();" 
            style="background-color:Transparent;border:none;display:none;"></button>
<script>
  function scrollInAlto() {
      window.scrollTo(0,0); <-- this one doesn't work
      //window.scroll(0,0); <-- this one works
  }
</script>
```

The only other thing I have is a small script to show and hide the button which scrolls the page: here it is.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(window).scroll(function(){
             var $temp = $("#scrollaInAlto").scrollTop();
             if (document.body.scrollTop > 50) {
                 $("#scrollaInAlto").show();
             } else {
                 $("#scrollaInAlto").hide();
             }
           });
        });
</script>
```

Why doesn't scrollTo work properly?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/kghag984/). Can you create an example that reproduces the issue? (a.k.a a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Yeah, it should be working just fine. Are you only using `scrollTo`? Not both `scrollTo` and `scroll` at the same time? https://jsfiddle.net/pavy/n2cbenja/

Comment: I wrote this: it's very similar to Mike's example, but in this case scrollTo(0,0) works fine. I don't really get it. https://jsfiddle.net/5vj7jc8m/3/